# Spen touch listener not working after update to Lollipop

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, samsung-mobile-sdk, stylus-pen, aspen

I am using SPenEventLibrary to recognise if touch is done by finger or Spen. It was working all the time until I updated to Android L.

Device: Galaxy Note 3.

Spen lib is up to date: libspen23.jar, pen-v3.1.8.jar

Android version: 5.0.

Code is simple:

```
mSPenEventLibrary.setSPenTouchListener(this, new SPenTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchFinger(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            if (ApplicationPreferences.get(mContext).getSPENWristGaurdOnOff() == false) {
                return handleEvent(event);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchPen(View view, MotionEvent event) {
            return handleEvent(event);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchButtonDown(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchButtonUp(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchPenEraser(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        }

    });
```

When I touch screen with Spen onTouchFinger() is called instead of onTouchPen(). On older Android versions onTouchPen() was called.

Comment: I am running into the same problem... Anyone please help!

Answer (score 1):

This is answer from samsung developers forum:

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

```
boolean done = false;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    if (event.getMetaState() == 0) {
        //Finger
        // Do whatever you need to do here
        done = true;
    }

    else if(event.getMetaState() == 512) {
        //Pen
        // Do whatever you need to do here
        done = true;
    }
}

else {
    if (event.getToolType(0) == MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_FINGER) {
        //Finger
        // Do whatever you need to do here
        done = true;
    }
    else if(event.getToolType(0) == MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_STYLUS) {
        //Pen
        // Do whatever you need to do here and then
        done = true;
    }
}
if (done)
    return true;
return super.onTouch(view, event);
```

}